# GetNumberOfConsoleFonts() работает некорректно

Tags: c#, winapi, консоль, interop

В своём консольном проекте на C# я решил реализовать возможность смены шрифта консоли средствами самой программы. Алгоритм действий:

1. С помощью WinAPI-функции GetNumberOfConsoleFonts() получить
   количество доступных для консоли шрифтов.
2. С помощью WinAPI-функции GetConsoleFontInfo() получить их индексы.
3. Последовательное применение WinAPI-функций SetConsoleFont() и
   GetCurrentConsoleFontEx() для каждого индекса, чтобы получить более
   детальную информацию о шрифтах.
4. На основе полученной информации организовать диалог с выбором шрифта.

Проблема в том, что GetNumberOfConsoleFonts() постоянно возвращает 0, делая все другие шаги бессмысленными. В чём может быть причина? Можно ли как-нибудь иначе получить количество доступных для консоли шрифтов или их индексы?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern uint GetNumberOfConsoleFonts();

//Использование:
uint fontsCount = GetNumberOfConsoleFonts();
```

У меня установлены Windows 10 и Visual Studio 2019.

***Дополнение от 26.08.2019:***
В общем, я так и не нашёл способа заставить функции `GetNumberOfConsoleFonts`, `GetConsoleFontInfo` и `SetConsoleFont` заработать. Пока вместо этого использую следующий алгоритм:

1. Из ветки реестра `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared
   Tools\Panose` (похоже, содержит имена и некоторые параметры шрифтов)
   получаю все пары `Имя:Значение`.
2. Выполняю отсеивание, оставляя только те, в которых четвёртый байт равен 0x09 (возможно именно это указывает на моноширинность шрифта).
3. Для каждого из оставшихся имён шрифтов последовательно применяю `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` и `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`, чтобы проверить может ли данный шрифт использоваться в консоли (если свойство `FaceName` структуры `CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX` что передаётся в `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` совпадает с свойством `FaceName` структуры `CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX` что возвращается `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`, значит консоль может использовать этот шрифт).
4. Из тех, что были успешно применены, формирую список, который и использую в диалоге выбора шрифта.

Comment: Вас не смущает то, что функции, мягко говоря, недокументированные? С чего Вы решили, что накопанных энтузиастами параметров достаточно для правильного (с Вашей точки зрения) их выполнения, что нет никаких дополнительных, необнаруженных, требований?

Comment: Я думаю, будет проще через SendMessage/PostMessage прошерстить консольное окно.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться АПИ http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions и играя с ф-цией SetCurrentConsoleFontEx выяснить какие режимы не поддерживаются.

Comment: Akina, использование недокуметированных функций меня смущает, но я не нашёл другого способа получить список доступных для консоли шрифтов. В любом случае, поскольку они не работают, я собираюсь от них отказаться и, если не будет выбора, захардкодить выбор из консольних шрифтов что входят в стандартную поставку Windows.
nick_n_a, можно подробнее?

Comment: Может проще сделать графическое приложение (WinForms, WPF)? Там-то проблем с установкой произвольных шрифтов не будет.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, я понимаю, но нужно именно консольное приложение.

Comment: Доступные консольные шрифты хранятся в ветке реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`. У меня на Win7 по умолчанию в нем только Consolas и Lucida Console; можно добавить другой моноширинный шрифт (например, Courier New), и он будет работать. Но непонятно, зачем делать диалог с выбором шрифта, если он уже есть в системе. И, так как вы не привели код с вызовом GetNumberOfConsoleFonts, сказать, почему он не работает, невозможно.

Comment: MSDN.WhiteNight, вручную менять настройки шрифта при каждом запуске программы не очень удобно, гораздо проще сохранить однажды сделанные настройки в файл конфигурации и в последующем автоматически их применять. Использовать регистр для получения информации не очень удобно (напр., у меня в свойствах консоли есть возможность выбрать из 11 шрифтов, тогда как в указаной вами ветке регистра присутствует лишь 4).

Comment: Импорт
`[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetNumberOfConsoleFonts();`
Использование
`uint fontsCount = GetNumberOfConsoleFonts();`
Как и было сказано, постоянно возвращается 0.

Comment: В Win7 работает (возвращает 11). "*вручную менять настройки шрифта при каждом запуске программы не очень удобно*" - помимо диалога "свойства" есть диалог "умолчания", который сохраняет свойства для выбранного приложения, так что они применяются автоматически при каждом запуске (хранится в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\(имя приложения)`)

Comment: MSDN.WhiteNight, в Windows 10 возвращает 0, возможно виноват переход на WinRT или что-то подобное. Что же касается сохранения настроек в реестр (неважно, системными средствами или средствами самой программы), это лишний риск оставить ненужный мусор после удаления программы, особенно если она портативная или удалялась без использования "родного" деинсталятора. P.S. Сама консоль как-то же определяет подходящие шрифты (те что представленны в окне свойств консоли), возможно в реестре как-нибудь указывается, является шрифт моноширинным или нет?

Answer (score 1):

В Windows 10 Microsoft внесли много улучшений в консоль. Это связано главным образом не с WinRT, а с появлением .NET Core и Windows Subsystem for Linux, которые оживили интерес к *NIX-софту, а он по большей части является именно консольным. Одно из таких улучшений - [возможность использовать в консоли любой моноширинный шрифт](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/6509589-allow-console-windows-to-use-any-monospace-font). Видимо, именно из-за этого недокументированная функция GetNumberOfConsoleFonts теперь возвращает 0 - никаких особых "консольных шрифтов" больше не существует, и она потеряла свой смысл.

На более ранних версиях Windows она работает, но особой необходимости в ней нет, так как список поддерживаемых шрифтов можно получить из ветки реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont` (она тоже не документированная, но на основе реестра список шрифтов построить вроде попроще, чем по предложенному алгоритму). По умолчанию, в ней только Consolas и Lucida Console. В нее можно добавить и другие моноширинные шрифты, удовлетворяющие [данным условиям](https://superuser.com/questions/1347724/how-can-i-add-additional-fonts-to-the-windows-console) - и они в какой-то мере будут работать - но это, скорее всего, плохая идея (см. [Why are console windows limited to Lucida Console and raster fonts?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070516-00/?p=26843)).

На Windows 10 же список поддерживаемых консолью шрифтов - это просто список всех моноширинных шрифтов. Помимо реестра, его можно получить стандартными средствами GDI/GDI+:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;

class Program
{     
    public static bool IsFixedPitch(Graphics graphics, FontFamily fam)
    {        
        Font font=new Font(fam, 10);
        using (font)
        {
            IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
            TEXTMETRIC metrics;
            IntPtr hFont = font.ToHfont();
            try
            {
                IntPtr hPreviousFont = SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
                bool res = GetTextMetrics(hDC, out metrics);
                if (res == false) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                SelectObject(hDC, hPreviousFont);
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(hFont);
                graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
            }
            return (metrics.tmPitchAndFamily & TMPF_FIXED_PITCH) == 0;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetTextMetrics(IntPtr hdc, out TEXTMETRIC lptm);

    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll")]
    static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hdc);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct TEXTMETRIC
    {
        public int tmHeight;
        public int tmAscent;
        public int tmDescent;
        public int tmInternalLeading;
        public int tmExternalLeading;
        public int tmAveCharWidth;
        public int tmMaxCharWidth;
        public int tmWeight;
        public int tmOverhang;
        public int tmDigitizedAspectX;
        public int tmDigitizedAspectY;
        public char tmFirstChar;
        public char tmLastChar;
        public char tmDefaultChar;
        public char tmBreakChar;
        public byte tmItalic;
        public byte tmUnderlined;
        public byte tmStruckOut;
        public byte tmPitchAndFamily;
        public byte tmCharSet;
    }

    const byte TMPF_FIXED_PITCH = 0x01;    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        InstalledFontCollection coll = new InstalledFontCollection();
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);

        using (g)
        {
            foreach (var family in coll.Families)
            {
                if (IsFixedPitch(g, family))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(family.GetName(0));
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }    
}
```